# Get results of output for each one value of the input - MATLAB ODE

Tags: mathematics, matlab

I am simulating a mass - damper - system in Matlab and I have the following vector (1x100) as input to my system:

```
ut = linspace(0, 10);
u = 5 * sin(2 * ut) + 10.5; % input of our system - external force
```

Now, I want to take the value of the output for each value of the input vector using this differential equation:

```
function dx = odefun_4(t,x)
    m = 15;
    b = 0.2;
    k = 2;   
    dx = [x(2); u/m - (b/m)*x(2) - (k/m)*x(1)];    
end
```

which is called from my main `.m` file like this:

```
[t,X] = ode45(@odefun_4, [0 10], [0;0])
```

I tried to pass the `u` vector by making it global variable but I get an error stating: `Dimensions of arrays being concatenated not consistent.`
I also tried to set the `Refine` parameter using `odeset` and the `options` argument of `ode45` solver but still don't get the desired results. I could really use some help.

Comment: What do you want $u$ actually to be, a smooth continuous function or a discretized function (zero or first order hold) at a fixed interval?

Comment: A smooth continuous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $u$ to be considered as a smooth continuous function, then you should define it as such since you also have $t$ available as well. So you could use:

```
function dx = odefun_4(t,x)
    m = 15;
    b = 0.2;
    k = 2;
    u = 5 * sin(2 * t) + 10.5;
    dx = [x(2); u/m - (b/m)*x(2) - (k/m)*x(1)];
end
```

I often also find it more convenient to use anonymous functions in Matlab, for example:

```
m = 15;
b = 0.2;
k = 2;
u = @(t) 5 * sin(2 * t) + 10.5;
odefun_4 = @(t,x) [x(2); u(t)/m - (b/m)*x(2) - (k/m)*x(1)];
```

Comment: Well, what you suggest works pretty fine. My issue is that for every value of `u` (which has 100 values) I want to get one value as output. I have a system and I want one output value for each input value. So , I need 100 output values as I have 100 input values.

Comment: @TeoProtoulis ode45 does not allow this. It is a variable step ode solver. You can specify that the time vector you input into ode45 is `linspace(0, 10)` and filter out any potentially additional time steps afterwards. Since your dynamics is linear you could also use [lsim](https://se.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lsim.html), which only works with constant time steps sampling.